# Reusable D3 chart with common code separated out

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a working D3 line graph using the framework outlined here: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/

Since I am creating a lot of charts I'd like to separate out the common elements (width and height for example) into a separate file, but I'm not really sure how to do that within the re-usable framework.

Here is the calling javascript file:

```
var common = commonChart()
    .main_height(400)
    .main_width(600);

var chart = multiLineChart()
    .x(function(d) { return d.date; })
    .y(function(d) { return d.number; })
    .yLabel("Number")
    .dimKey(function(d) { return d._id.env; })
    .yTickFormat(function(d) { return d3.round(d); })
    .yScale(d3.scale.sqrt())
    .color(d3.scale.category10());

d3.json('data/datafile.json', function(data) {
    d3.select("#graph")
        .datum(data)
        .call(common)
        .call(chart);
});
```

The common file is this:

```
function commonChart() {

    var main_width, main_height;

    function chart(selection) {

        console.log(main_height);

    }

    // Get/set main_width
    chart.main_width = function(value) {
        if (!arguments.length) return main_width;
        main_width = value;
        return chart;
    }

    // Get/set main_height
    chart.main_height = function(value) {
        if (!arguments.length) return main_height;
        main_height = value;
        return chart;
    }

}
```

The multiLineChart has all the core logic for the line graph itself.  When I run this I end up with `Cannot read property 'main_height' of undefined`.  Is there a way to do this with D3 using the reusable chart framework?

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, this isn't possible. Everything you want to be in the component has to be in the same function/closure. You could however use components inside other components for repeated functionality.

Comment: OK, I had my doubts about whether it would work.  Can you elaborate a little more about putting components inside other components?   Thanks!

Comment: You don't put them into each other, but use one component inside another. You could for example have a bar chart component that internally uses the axis component.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the exact same problem recently. Building a library of charts and not wanting to copy-paste all of the common properties when I make a new type of chart.

Here is the solution that I have come up with:

```js
Chart = function module() {
        // properties
        this._width = 800;
        this._height = 600;
        this._margin = {
            top: 10,
            bottom: 10,
            left: 20,
            right: 5
        };
        this._title = '';
    }

    // doing stuff
    Chart.prototype.plot = function () {
        console.log('The plot function has not been defined.');
    }

    // setting the properties
    Chart.prototype.width = function (_x) {
        if (!arguments.length) return this._width;
        this._width = _x;
        return this;
    }
    Chart.prototype.height = function (_x) {
        if (!arguments.length) return this._height;
        this._height = _x;
        return this;
    }
    Chart.prototype.margin = function (_x) {
        if (!arguments.length) return this._margin;
        this._margin = _x;
        return this;
    }
    Chart.prototype.title = function (_x) {
        if (!arguments.length) return this._title;
        this._title = _x;
        return this;
    }

    // creating a new type of chart, which inherits from Chart.
    BarChart.prototype = new Chart(); // Here's where the inheritance occurs 
    BarChart.prototype.constructor = BarChart;
    BarChart.prototype.parent = Chart.prototype;

    function BarChart() {
    }
    // 'overriding' the .plot function
    BarChart.prototype.plot = function (_selection) {
        var myTitle = this.parent.title.call(this);
        _selection.each(function (_data) {
            console.log('Plotting ' + _data.length + ' bars of data. The chart is called: ' + myTitle);
        });
    }

    
    
    // usage
    var myBarChart1 = new BarChart();
    myBarChart1.width(250)
        .height(200)
        .title('Population Growth');
    myBarChart1.plot(d3.select("#chart").datum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])); // Plotting 6 bars of data. The chart is called: Population Growth

    var myBarChart2 = new BarChart();
    myBarChart2.width(50)
        .height(500)
        .title('Music Sales');
    myBarChart2.plot(d3.select("#chart").datum([1, 2, 3, 4])); // Plotting 4 bars of data. The chart is called: Music Sales
```

```html
 <div id="chart"></div>
```

It means that I only have to create common properties, such as width and height, once, rather than in every single type of chart that I create. The resulting object calls can be chained, like d3.js. The only thing that isn't consistent with d3.js usage is that you have to call the .plot() function to actually draw the chart. I've been unable to figure out how to call this directly from the BarChart function (I've tried returning a plot function from BarChart, but that didn't work).

If you want to read around the subject, here is a really great article on inheritance in JavaScript: http://phrogz.net/JS/classes/OOPinJS2.html