# Reusable d3.js Components And Inheritance

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to create a library of reusable d3.js components along the lines of Mike Bostock's [Toward Reusable Charts](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/), and am having some difficulty in creating reusable components that reuse code internally.

The library, and its *i*-th component, look something like this:

```
d3.library = {}

d3.library.component_i = function module() {
    var width = 800,
        height = 800;

    function exports(_selection) {
        ...
    }

    exports.width = function(_width) {
        if(!arguments.length) 
            return width;
        width = _width;
        return this;
    }
    exports.height = function(_height) {
        if(!arguments.length) 
            return height;
        height = _height;
        return this;
    }

    ....

    return exports
}
```

Some of the code, e.g. the "members" and "methods" `height` and `width`,  is essentially boilerplate code which I'm copy-pasting for any component *i*. I'd like to reuse code, instead.

In a "classic" OO language, e.g., Python, it would be natural to write some `_BaseComponent` base class, and subclass it. This base class would contain the common members:

```
class _BaseComponent(object):
   ...  

   @property
   def width(self):
       ...

   @width.setter
   def width(self, width_):
       ...


class ComponentI(_BaseComponent):

    ...

    # width and height inherited

    ...
```

Since it is a Javascript library, however, I'd like to retain the Javascript and d3.js "feel": function chaining, the select-call paradigm, and so forth. I've read up a bit on prototypal inheritance in Javascript (e.g., in [Javscript: The Good Parts](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596517748.do)), but the objects there don't seem to be defined along the lines of the above code (i.e., a function with local variables as "data members" for a single exported function, and "methods" which serve as accessors to the "data members").

I can't figure out how to create a library such that it simultaneously

1. has a reusable hierarchy internally
2. meshes well with the rest of d3.js, esp. externally

A [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23680520/reusable-d3-chart-with-common-code-separated-out?rq=1) raises the same points, basically, but asks for help with a specific solution direction. Any solution which addresses the above 2 points is fine here, even if it involves changing all the components' structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the exact same problem recently. Building a library of charts and not wanting to copy-paste all of the common `exports` properties when I make a new type of chart.

Here is the solution that I have come up with:

```js
Chart = function module() {
        // properties
        this._width = 800;
        this._height = 600;
        this._margin = {
            top: 10,
            bottom: 10,
            left: 20,
            right: 5
        };
        this._title = '';
    }

    // doing stuff
    Chart.prototype.plot = function () {
        console.log('The plot function has not been defined.');
    }

    // setting the properties
    Chart.prototype.width = function (_x) {
        if (!arguments.length) return this._width;
        this._width = _x;
        return this;
    }
    Chart.prototype.height = function (_x) {
        if (!arguments.length) return this._height;
        this._height = _x;
        return this;
    }
    Chart.prototype.margin = function (_x) {
        if (!arguments.length) return this._margin;
        this._margin = _x;
        return this;
    }
    Chart.prototype.title = function (_x) {
        if (!arguments.length) return this._title;
        this._title = _x;
        return this;
    }

    // creating a new type of chart, which inherits from Chart.
    BarChart.prototype = new Chart(); // Here's where the inheritance occurs 
    BarChart.prototype.constructor = BarChart;
    BarChart.prototype.parent = Chart.prototype;

    function BarChart() {
    }
    // 'overriding' the .plot function
    BarChart.prototype.plot = function (_selection) {
        var myTitle = this.parent.title.call(this);
        _selection.each(function (_data) {
            console.log('Plotting ' + _data.length + ' bars of data. The chart is called: ' + myTitle);
        });
    }

    
    
    // usage
    var myBarChart1 = new BarChart();
    myBarChart1.width(250)
        .height(200)
        .title('Population Growth');
    myBarChart1.plot(d3.select("#chart").datum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])); // Plotting 6 bars of data. The chart is called: Population Growth

    var myBarChart2 = new BarChart();
    myBarChart2.width(50)
        .height(500)
        .title('Music Sales');
    myBarChart2.plot(d3.select("#chart").datum([1, 2, 3, 4])); // Plotting 4 bars of data. The chart is called: Music Sales
```

```html
 <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
 <div id="chart"></div>
```

It means that I only have to create common properties, such as width and height, once, rather than in every single type of chart that I create. The resulting object calls can be chained, like d3.js. The only thing that isn't consistent with d3.js usage is that you have to call the .plot() function to actually draw the chart. I've been unable to figure out how to call this directly from the BarChart function (I've tried returning a plot function from BarChart, but that didn't work).

If you want to read around the subject, here is a really great article on inheritance in JavaScript: http://phrogz.net/JS/classes/OOPinJS2.html

Comment: Many thanks! This was very detailed and useful! (As a very minor point, the "Run code snippet" is cool, but didn't work for me.)

Comment: Ah, I didn't include a reference to d3.js! It works now. If you hit run and then look at your console output, you'll see the messages from the .plot() function.

Comment: Indeed it does! Many thanks for both the answer and the consideration of the Run code snippet thingy.

Answer (score 0):

IMO the ideal approach for developing reusable components is to develop them as components packaged in individual modules that rely on each other generating still higher level components.

Developing a hierarchy of objects would be difficult to manage and would also curtail the flexibility of the library.

Refer:
http://www.cloudshapes.co.uk/exp/london-d3-talk/#/9

The actual code reuse is not by inheriting properties, but by developing visualizations as a composition of disparate components.

Thus the reuse happens at the component level instead of the property/behaviour level.

NVD3 is one library which follows this structure.

The above code uses closures instead of relying on prototypal inheritance and can not be extended in the way you want as far as I am aware.

Comment: Thanks, @prashant, but I'm not sure how that answers my question. It's very possible my terminology was inaccurate. The slides you reference recommend building modules from components. The components are built according to the style in my original question. My question is how to share code between these components (using the width and height accessors as a concrete example), instead of copy-pasting it between components.